# Is there a way to see your progress toward badges?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

CV has tons of badges. Some require that you do XXXX task XXXX times (e.g. edit 500 posts). Is there a way to see your progress toward these goals?

Comment: You can use the data explorer to get a somewhat delayed progress report: http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/queries?q=badge (Disclaimer: I haven't tried any of these.) For the editor badges, just go to users and click on the editors tab and sort as desired to find yourself, I guess.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that

Comment: There are several questions along this line in the SE meta, [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=see+progress+towards+badges) is a list of returns from such a search, which one is appropriate will depend on what exactly you want to know.

Comment: Thanks @gung.  Very useful threads there.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is something that has been declined for a long time. For more information, please see this post:

[Badge progress reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports)

Fortunately, **cardinal** linked to the data query that serves in a pinch!